# Getting wrong result for binary to decimal even after using BigInt() in javascript

Tags: javascript, binary, decimal, let, bigint

I am trying to add two given binary strings after converting them to decimals(Numbers) and then converting back the resulting decimal(Number) to string.

I am getting the wrong binary to decimal even after using `BigInt()`.

```
let a = "10100000100100110110010000010101111011011001101110111111111101000000101111001110001111100001101";
let b="110101001011101110001111100110001010100001101011101010000011011011001011101111001100000011011110011";

var twoSum = function(a, b) {
let a1=BigInt(parseInt(a, 2));
 let b1=BigInt(parseInt(b,2));
let aStr=a1.toString(10);
let bStr=b1.toString(10);

console.log(aStr)
console.log(bStr)
};

console.log(twoSum(a, b));
```

Output:

```
        24847893154024981755840167936
        526700554598729745018195542016
```

Correct result is : `24847893154024981730169397005` & `526700554598729746900966573811`

I don't why I am getting the wrong result of binary to decimal.

Comment: `24847893154024981730169397005` is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. You can directly use `BigInt` just adding "0b" in to your string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseInt` returns a `Number`. Due to `Number`'s limited precision being less than the length of your input strings, you've lost precision at that point. Converting that `Number` to a `BigInt` afterwards doesn't bring the lost precision back.

The solution is to convert the strings to `BigInt` directly. There was supposed to be a `BigInt.parseInt` function, but TC39 (the committee that standardizes JavaScript) never got around to finishing that. In the meantime, for non-decimal inputs, the `BigInt` constructor does understand strings starting with `0x...` (hex), `0o...` (octal), and `0b...` (binary). The latter is what you want in this case. So you could fix your code as follows:

```js
function parseBinaryToBigInt(a) {
  return BigInt('0b' + a);
}

function twoSum(a, b) {
  let a1 = parseBinaryToBigInt(a);
  let b1 = parseBinaryToBigInt(b);
  let aStr = a1.toString(10);
  let bStr = b1.toString(10);

  console.log(aStr)
  console.log(bStr)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let a = "10100000100100110110010000010101111011011001101110111111111101000000101111001110001111100001101";
// Binary to decimal
const d = BigInt('0b' + a);
// Turn the binary
const b = BigInt(a);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about what your code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: `BigInt('0b' + a)` doesn't convert anything to decimal; it converts a string to a BigInt (which, in today's browsers, uses a binary representation internally, but you can't see that from the outside). `BigInt(a)` is just incorrect for the problem at hand.

Comment: Its length is always greater than the maximum length, but I'm just giving you the way to think about it, if you can store it with string(), turn it into a string